# Single-value field returned as multi-value from query

Tags: solr, solr.net

I'm using Solr.NET to index data and later query it on a local Solr server (Solr.net v0.4, Solr v5.3.1), and getting strange exceptions.

My indexed record is a simple class (simplified here):

```
public class Record
{
    [SolrUniqueKey]
    public long Id {get;set;}

    [SolrUniqueKey]
    public string Data {get;set;}
}
```

Which I'm adding to the index by calling ISolrOperations.Add(). I didn't define the schema beforehand - it was autogenerated by the data I put in.

Elsewhere, I'm querying this index using ISolrReadOnlyOperations.Query(), asking only for the Id field.  This query apparently returns results, but crashes with an ArgumentException:

> "Could not convert value 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to property 'Id' of document type My.Namespace.Record"

Meaning that while I stored the Id property as a `long`, it's being retrieved as an `ArrayList` of `longs`. I get the same error if I try to retrieve other fields - I store one string, but retrieve a collection of them. This crashes, because it's trying to create an instance of `Record`, where the `Id` property is a single `long`.

Browsing the index via the web interface shows that the property really is multi-valued - the JSON I see contains an *array* for all properties. Likewise, in the schema browser, I can see that my fields are defined as multivalued (for Properties and Schema, not Indexing). In the index's managed-schema file I can see my fields are defined as `strings` (for string fields) or `tlongs` for the numeric field.

1. Why is Solr (or Solr.Net) indexing my single-value fields as multi-valued?
2. Can I prevent this from happening without manually editing the schema? Using a field attribute, perhaps?
3. Can I retrieve only a single value for a multi-valued property, so in case I can't fix the schema, I can simply retrieve the data into my single-valued `Record` object?

Comment: What is the field definition in the schema? The schema is what decides whether a field is returned as multiValued or not (and no, that can't be overridden from the client side).

Comment: @MatsLindh There's no predefined schema. It's inferred by the data. That was the problem - the defaults for data-driven documents are multivalued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found both a solution and a workaround.

1. New indexes/cores in Solr 5.3.1, if not given a solrconfig.xml file explicitly, copy the default file found in `<solr dir>\server\solr\configsets\data_driven_schema_configs\conf`.
   This file defines an updateProcessRequestChain defining what happens when new documents are added without a schema. By default, the types defined there are multivalued:

   `<processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
     <lst name="typeMapping">
       <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Long</str>
       <str name="valueClass">java.lang.Integer</str>
       <str name="fieldType">tlongs</str>
     </lst>
     </processor>`

Note the `strings` and `tlongs` data types. 
To prevent this, you can change the `solrconfig.xml` in your core's `conf` folder to use the single-valued data types (`string`, `tlong`, etc), or change the default value for newly created cores.

2. The workaround is to read the results as a `Dictionary<string,object>`, instead of having Solr.NET deserialize the results into a document object automatically.

This means initializing a second Solr operations object for this type:

```
   Startup.Init<Record>(indexUrl); // Typed
   Startup.Init<Dictionary<string, object>>(indexUrl); // Untyped.
```

and later, get an instance of `ISolrOperations<Dictionary<string,object>>` and manually read my `Key` and `Data` attributes from it, casting the `object` payload to an `ArrayList` and extracting the value.

Comment: Do you happen to know what can be done for strings as well ? Should I add a : `<lst name="typeMapping">
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.String</str>
    <str name="valueClass">java.lang.String</str>
    <str name="fieldType">string</str>
  </lst>` in there? :^)

Comment: changing tlongs, strings etc to tlong, string is fine, but for my case, the schema is mixed: there are few fields that are actually multi-valued and some are single-valued. What can be work around/solution?